# Three Aliases in SQL

Tags: sql, pivot

I have confused to view three condition using AS in SQL, this is my table

```
id | Fruit
___________
1  | Apel
2  | Orange
3  | Apel
4  | Manggo
___________
```

**This is my first query:**

```
SELECT
COUNT(fruit) AS apelfruit
FROM fruit_table
WHERE fruit = 'Apel'
```

**Output:**

```
apelfruit
_________
    2
```

**But when I do this:**

```
SELECT
COUNT(fruit) AS apelfruit,
COUNT(fruit) AS orangefruit,
COUNT(fruit) AS manggofruit
FROM fruit_table
WHERE fruit = 'Apel'
AND fruit = 'Orange'
AND fruit = 'Manggo'
```

**The output was zero (0):**

```
 apelfruit | orangefruit | manggofruit
 ____________________________________
       0            0            0
```

I'm little bit confused whats wrong. Anyone can help me I'd appreciate very much. Thank you.

Comment: Your where clause is always going to return false. The field cannot be three values at the same time. You need a group by, then a COUNT on each group.

Comment: @nicomp So I rather has each query for each condition?

Comment: I don't follow your question. I will say that your premise is flawed because when a fruit is added, the query will have to be hand-edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try below way

```
SELECT
sum(case when fruit = 'Apel' then 1 else 0 end) AS apelfruit,
sum(case when fruit = 'Orange' then 1 else 0 end) AS orangfruit,
sum(case when fruit = 'Manggo' then 1 else 0 end) AS manggofruit
FROM fruit_table
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer using `COUNT` here, for brevity:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(CASE WHEN fruit = 'Apel'   THEN 1 END) AS apelfruit,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN fruit = 'Orange' THEN 1 END) AS orangfruit,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN fruit = 'Manggo' THEN 1 END) AS manggofruit
FROM fruit_table;
```

As @nicomp has pointed out, the limitation to doing a pivot query this way is that the columns which appear in the output are hard-coded, and more code must be added for new conditional counts.  But, the only real way around this is to use dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 0):

The condition is your problem a fruit can't equal to "apel" *and* to "mango"
it should be "apel" **or** "apel"

Since just counting fruits, will always count **all** fruits, you also need to count with a condition, in this solution, summing 1 or 0, based on ghe condition:

```
SELECT
SUM(IF(fruit='Apel', 1,0)) AS apelfruit,
SUM(IF(fruit='Orange', 1,0)) AS orangfruit,
SUM(IF(fruit='Manggo', 1,0)) AS manggofruit
FROM fruit_table WHERE fruit IN ('Apel', 'Orange', 'Manggo')
;
```

Comment: That is invalid standard SQL.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name why?

Comment: @nicomp notice that the question was for pivot, that's the way to do it...

Comment: There is no `IF` in (standard) SQL

Comment: @GuyLouzon if that's true, where's the PIVOT keyword?

Comment: @nicomp pivot is not a statement in all SQL statements